# How Virtualbox "VBoxmanage mediumproperty <set|get|delete> <uuid|filename> <property> [value]" works?

Tags: virtualbox

I trued to just *read* some properties with *get* like this:

```
VBoxManage mediumproperty get c783a12e-d735-4b02-866c-3ce39e55ac6d "Capacity"
```

and I tried:
Location mtype type state device hotpluggable port tport

all with and without quotes. I always get the same result:

```
VBoxManage: error: Property '--mtype' does not exist
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "GetProperty(Bstr(pszProperty).raw(), strVal.asOutParam())" at line 1734 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

So how can I read properties with this command?